# Crossfading Image Overlapping Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

So I have created a crossfade effect that transitions between two images. These images are within a bootstrap column with text in another column beside it. My problem is that when the browser is smaller than 990px (width) the bootstrap column does not respond like is supposed it because the image is placed behind the text and not above it. I know it has something to do with the `position: absolute` because when I take it out, it works properly. However, you need it for the crossfade to work.

Is there any way of resolving this issue, either a better way of creating a crossfade between images or how to fix it in its current state?

https://jsfiddle.net/8kec7wnw/8/

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the use of `col-md-4` and `col-md-8`. These classes in Bootstrap affect the layout at screen sizes above and below 992 pixels. Adjust these to `col-sm-4` and `col-sm-8` to make the breakpoint 768px, or `col-xs-4` and `col-xs-8` to set the breakpoint to mobile screens and up.

However, because the images are fixed width, this layout will never be truly responsive. I'd recommend containing the images within a Bootstrap column, and setting their size based upon the column.

Set the class of `img-responsive` to ensure the images resize with the column.

Answer (score 0):

[Toby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4008056/toby) is Right. I tested his answer (https://jsfiddle.net/omarlin25/8kec7wnw/13/) and works.

```
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-4 slides">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i18083/icons-land/vista-style-emoticons/Cool.ico">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/692846828132282371/foet1dNz.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 content-padding">
                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi venenatis nisi condimentum, elementum nibh non, imperdiet diam. Ut lobortis mollis varius.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi venenatis nisi condimentum, elementum nibh non, imperdiet diam. Ut lobortis mollis varius.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi venenatis nisi condimentum, elementum nibh non, imperdiet diam. Ut lobortis mollis varius.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi venenatis nisi condimentum, elementum nibh non, imperdiet diam. Ut lobortis mollis varius.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
               </div>
           </div>
```

PD. I tried to write this in a comment but I do not have the enough rhights yet